Use polars when-then-otherwise on multiple output columns at once
Assume I have this dataframe
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'item':         ['CASH', 'CHECK', 'DEBT', 'CHECK', 'CREDIT', 'CASH'],
    'quantity':     [100, -20, 0, 10, 0, 0],
    'value':        [99, 47, None, 90, None, 120],
    'value_other':  [97, 57, None, 91, None, 110],
    'value_other2': [94, 37, None, 93, None, 115],
})

┌────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ item   ┆ quantity ┆ value ┆ value_other ┆ value_other2 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ CASH   ┆ 100      ┆ 99    ┆ 97          ┆ 94           │
│ CHECK  ┆ -20      ┆ 47    ┆ 57          ┆ 37           │
│ DEBT   ┆ 0        ┆ null  ┆ null        ┆ null         │
│ CHECK  ┆ 10       ┆ 90    ┆ 91          ┆ 93           │
│ CREDIT ┆ 0        ┆ null  ┆ null        ┆ null         │
│ CASH   ┆ 0        ┆ 120   ┆ 110         ┆ 115          │
└────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘

Now I want to set all value columns to 0 for all rows where value is null and quantity == 0.
Right now I have this solution
cols = ['value', 'value_other', 'value_other2']
df   = df.with_columns([
    pl.when(pl.col('value').is_null() & (pl.col('quantity') == 0))
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(pl.col(col))
    .alias(col)
    for col in cols
])

which correctly gives
┌────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ item   ┆ quantity ┆ value ┆ value_other ┆ value_other2 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ CASH   ┆ 100      ┆ 99    ┆ 97          ┆ 94           │
│ CHECK  ┆ -20      ┆ 47    ┆ 57          ┆ 37           │
│ DEBT   ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CHECK  ┆ 10       ┆ 90    ┆ 91          ┆ 93           │
│ CREDIT ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CASH   ┆ 0        ┆ 120   ┆ 110         ┆ 115          │
└────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘

However, I feel this is very inefficient as my when condition is executed for every value column. Is there a way to achieve this using only polar internal functions & without the native for-loop?

You can pass list of column names into pl.col() and when\then\otherwise accepts Expr which can contain multiple columns.
cols = ['value', 'value_other', 'value_other2']

df.with_columns(
    pl
    .when((pl.col.quantity != 0) | pl.col.value.is_not_null())
    .then(pl.col(cols))
    .otherwise(0)
)

# or

df.with_columns(
    pl
    .when(pl.col.quantity != 0).then(pl.col(cols))
    .when(pl.col.value.is_not_null()).then(pl.col(cols))
    .otherwise(0)
)

shape: (6, 5)
┌────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ item   ┆ quantity ┆ value ┆ value_other ┆ value_other2 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ CASH   ┆ 100      ┆ 99    ┆ 97          ┆ 94           │
│ CHECK  ┆ -20      ┆ 47    ┆ 57          ┆ 37           │
│ DEBT   ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CHECK  ┆ 10       ┆ 90    ┆ 91          ┆ 93           │
│ CREDIT ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CASH   ┆ 0        ┆ 120   ┆ 110         ┆ 115          │
└────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘


i wanted to explicitly condition on value and quantity, and then set all value columns to 0. Is there something like df.with_columns(pl.col('value').is_null() & (pl.col('quantity') == 0)).then(pl.col(cols).fill(0)).otherwise(pl.col(cols)))?

Ah now I see, I misread the requirements. See updated answer.

Apply the condition to all columns at once. Also replace alias by name.keep:
cols = ['value', 'value_other', 'value_other2']

(df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('value').is_null() & (pl.col('quantity') == 0))
    .then(0)
    .otherwise(pl.col(cols))
    .name.keep()
))

Output:
┌────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ item   ┆ quantity ┆ value ┆ value_other ┆ value_other2 │
│ ---    ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str    ┆ i64      ┆ i64   ┆ i64         ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ CASH   ┆ 100      ┆ 99    ┆ 97          ┆ 94           │
│ CHECK  ┆ -20      ┆ 47    ┆ 57          ┆ 37           │
│ DEBT   ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CHECK  ┆ 10       ┆ 90    ┆ 91          ┆ 93           │
│ CREDIT ┆ 0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0           ┆ 0            │
│ CASH   ┆ 0        ┆ 120   ┆ 110         ┆ 115          │
└────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘

